# Не работает Instantiate в методе Start()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в том, что когда запускаю сцену, префаб дома не появляется, но когда я вручную добавляю его на сцену, а потом запускаю ее, то начинает появляться куча копий этого префаба.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HouseController : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject housePrefab;
    private bool isGrounded = false;

    private void Start() {
        CreateHouse();
        CreateFloor();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        MoveByHalfCircle();
        IsSpaceButtonDown();
    }

    private void CreateHouse() {
        Instantiate(housePrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        isGrounded = false;
    }

    private void CreateFloor() {
        
    }

    private void IsSpaceButtonDown() {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            SpawnHouse();
        }
    }

    private void MoveByHalfCircle() {
        if(!isGrounded) {
            rb2d.gravityScale = 0;
        } else {
            rb2d.gravityScale = 4;
        }
        Vector3 vector = transform.right;
        var min = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(0, 0));
        var max = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2(1, 1));

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + vector, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(transform.position.x > max.x - 2 || transform.position.x < min.x + 2) {
            speed = -speed;
        }
    }

    private void SpawnHouse() {
        isGrounded = true;
        CreateHouse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы добавили housePrefab в инспекторе? Есть ли какие-то ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что скрипт вы разместили на самом объекте House, а не на пустом объекте, заранее выставленном на сцене. Если это так - в этом и есть проблема.

P.S. Репутация не позволяет писать комментарии.

Comment: хм, возможно, я об этом как-то не подумал, надо проверить)